# Generate text file in runtime using template

Tags: c#, .net

I am using .NET Core 1.1 and need to create a text file at runtime. For instance:

```
import MyLib

a = 5
MyLib.doSomeStuff(a)
```

The only thing I need to do is to create a text file, but where the value of `a` is given by some calculations done in my C# code. Ideally, I would like to have something similar to this in my C# code:

```
// Variable to pass to be set on the script
int a = 5;
// Create the Python script and save to some .py file
CreatePythonScript(a);
```

Note that this is a minimal example. In practice, my script has hundreds of lines and hundreds of variables, so writing a text file manually with successive calls to `Write()` would not be so clever.

I checked the T4 framework but I don't think this is what I need. What can I use for this?

Comment: And what was lacking in  T4?

Comment: Well, what i would do is having a text file with the template, and having some _placeholders_ there. That way,the only thing you'll need to do is reading the whole file, `Replace` the placeholders with the values and writing the result to another file

Comment: Have a look at this [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) it works on Core

Comment: @Pikoh how would i do that?

Comment: Well, I was going to add an answer but @Balázs was quicker :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just write a sample file with some clevery defined placeholders in them and from then on, it is just a replace all operation.

For example:

```
import MyLib

a = `a`
MyLib.doSomeStuff(a)
```

So, what you have to do is find out how you could insert placeholders so that it results in strings that otherwise could not be found in the text and therefore you don't replace anything that shouldn't be replaced. In this example, (I don't know Python at all) assuming that backticks (`) would never normally appear, you could use them to either prefix, postfix, or completely wrap the parts to where dynamic values should be inserted. You must also take into account special parts where they could otherwise appear in extreme cases: comments, string literals, etc.

One more thing to pay attention to is that **your logic should prioritize placeholders**, so that if there is a placeholder which is the prefix of another one, then you must replace the longer one first, otherwise by replacing the shorter one, you invalidate the longer one. Note that if you don't prefix or postfix but *wrap* the parts with character(s) that could not normally appear then one placeholder can never be the prefix/suffix of another one.

With these said, I only suggest choosing an approach as plain and simple as this is if the templates are simple, otherwise, you should certainly look for a dedicated tool.

An example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> keysAndReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Initialize the dictionary here.

// Custom logic to perform key prioritization. More on it below.
IEnumerable<string> prioritizedKeys = PrioritizeKeys(keysAndReplacements.Keys);

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\sample.txt"))
{
    string allText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    foreach (string key in prioritizedKeys)
    {
        allText = allText.Replace(key, keysAndReplacements[key]);
    }
}
```

This logic simply reads the whole template, and replaces the placeholders with the values. The keys of the dictionary are the placeholders (together with prefixes **or** suffixes **or** pre+suffixes).

The detailing of 'more on it below':

- As I said, if there are both prefixes and suffixes for the placeholders, then (assuming the prefix and postfix characters otherwise never appear) it is impossible for collisions to occur.
- The most straightforward implementation would be to order by key length descending, since then you start with the longer keys first and therefore collisions can only occur (well, that isn't even a collision) if the placeholders are the exact same. Since Dictionary doesn't allow duplicated keys, you would be in trouble if you attempted to add the same key twice.
- To be safe, don't just use 1-1 character at the start and at the end. Use several wrappers so that you decrease the chance of the string occurring somewhere where you don't actually want it to be replaced. For example: `§§§a§§§`. The less common the characters you use are the lower the chance of replacing something you don't want, for example, in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do I do the replacing?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just for reference, what libs are out there to perform this?

Comment: I can't tell an exact one since I've never needed to use one, that's why I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: One important thing to watch out for in this solution is that you don't have overlapping keys like `tree` and `treeview`. In case you replace them in the wrong order your result would be messed up.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel yes, if you had read my answer, you'd have noticed that I've covered that :)